How can I know how polluted a river is?
I'd like to swim in a river. How can I know how much pollution there is in that river that could endanger a swimmer?
I'm interested in solutions both before accessing the river (e.g., a pollution map), and after accessing the river (e.g., seeing 100 dead fishes floating around, noticing a yellow stream coming from an adjacent factory or a smelling a putrid odor). The 2024 study {1} has an interesting pollution map but it's rather coarse-grained. Assume that local authorities don't have or don't share that information.
For example:

Is there a website where I can type the river's name and see its pollution level, possibly based on time  and location?
Is there a small, reasonably priced water testing kit I could use?


References:

{1} Gómez-Sanabria, A., Lindl, F. The crucial role of circular waste management systems in cutting waste leakage into aquatic environments. Nat Commun 15, 5443 (2024). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-024-49555-9


The world is a big place, is there a part of the world you are more likely to be in? This is more for online than for at the spot.

I would be seriously concerned if the government attempted to keep harmful intoxications of rivers under the cover.

@PMF I didn't mean intentional cover-ups but just failure to communicate about water quality.

@Willeke thanks, I'm typically in the US but water quality in the US is pretty well documented, at least compared to many other countries, but sometimes I travel for work or for vacation, in which case it can be anywhere.

You could also ask some locals.  That also has the advantage that river swimming can be quite hazardous for other reasons than chemicals or biological contamination.

Water can also be made toxic, not because of pollution, but by proliferation of certain algae and cyanobacteria which produce toxic algal blooms.

I don't know about pollution maps, but there's no such thing as a cheap, general-purpose pollution testing kit.  Cheap testing kits are targeted at specific contaminants, so if you're worried about lead, you get a lead-testing kit, if you're worried about cyanide, you get a cyanide testing kit, if you're worried about sewage, you get a coliform testing kit, and so on.  A general-purpose test for any possible contaminant requires a laboratory and equipment typically costing millions of dollars.
Maps are also frequently for specific contaminants.  For example, the one linked in your question is about untreated sewage (and is an estimate, at that).  It doesn't show other sources of contamination, such as mine runoff.
